# Email notifications don't seem to work for me

Tags: bug, status-completed, email-notification

I don't use SE sites a lot, but when I do, I have had perennial trouble with email notifications (not every time but often). This time I posted in http://tex.stackexchange.com two days ago, and after not hearing anything for a day and a half, I checked and discovered two answers and two comments that were posted within a couple hours of my post. My preferences say I should get email notifications every three hours, but I never got anything. Is there another setting I should check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query has been on my list for a while but we've been queued up on work. I just pushed a fix for the job (a new filtered index) and emails should resume sending on the next pass (within 24 hours).

Comment: Thanks! Your fix is verified - I'm getting email! :)

Answer (score 3):

The best thing for you to do is [contact us directly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/contact) and link to this meta post. I just checked all of your account settings and you *should* be getting unread inbox notifications every 3 hours.

We'll need to verify that the email address is correct, perhaps send a test, etc - this is all stuff where we talk about information that shouldn't be public, and need to coordinate with you.

Please check your spam folder just to be sure, but I'm not aware of any issues around getting mail delivered to your provider.